# Videos created using FFmpeg are not being displayed in web browsers such as Chrome, Firefox, and Safari

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am attempting to generate an MP4 video by combining images and audio with FFmpeg-Kit-React-Native but it is not being displayed in web browsers.

For your reference I'm attaching the package link below:
[ffmpeg-kit-react-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg-kit-react-native?activeTab=readme)

The commands I utilized to produce the video are as follows:

1. `-i ${imageFile} -i ${audioFile?.uri} -vf scale=480:360 -f mp4 ${outputFile}`
2. `-loop 1 -i ${imageFile} -i ${audioFile.uri} -shortest -acodec copy ${outputFile}`
3. `-i ${imageFile} -i ${audioFile?.uri} -b:v 2M -vf scale=480:360:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=480:360:-1:-1 -pix_fmt yuv420p ${outputFile}`
4. `-i ${imageFile} -i ${audioFile?.uri} -vf scale=480:360:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=480:360:-1:-1 -f mp4 ${outputFile}`

[I have attached a link to the video I generated using a single image and one audio file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1APO5A8T5haCdPFNIAQ942WS3Wub49Uvp/view?usp=sharing)

Additionally, I am unable to install external encoding packages such as full-gpl, full, https-gpl, and min-gpl on the Android side.

Answer (score 0):

You do not specify a video codec for your format (`-f mp4`). In that case `ffmpeg` uses 'a' default video codec. If i run `ffprobe` on your file, the output for the video stream is:

- `Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile)`

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/Containers#mpeg-4_mp4, `firefox` does not support this codec (as to the other browsers, please do your own research).

The solution is to use one of the supported video codecs, e.g. AVC (H.264) or VP9.

To specify the H.264 codec in `ffmpeg` use the argument `-codec:v libx264`.

To list all available encoders, run: `ffmpeg -encoders`

If the required codecs are not listed in the output, you have to configure `ffmpeg` and specify, e.g. `--enable libx264`.

See also: [FFmpeg - H.264 Video Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264)